# How to move sidebar to the left in shop pages?

Tags: woocommerce

I am using woocommerce for the first time and have searched for answers to this question for hours now. Found none. I'm exhausted and really grateful if someone wishes to help out.

I am using woocommerce on a self-created child theme. The main shop page uses a theme-template called "page-left-sidebar", which normally places the sidebar with widgets  to the left of the page. This option would look good in the web shop that I'm trying to create.

But Woocommerce templates override my custom templates, and although I get the correct "page-left-sidebar"-template's sidebar widgets, I see with my eyes and also when investigating with firebug, that woocommerce is calling the "page-right-sidebar"-template's main & sidebar css rules instead those of the left-sidebar-template. The page-right-sidebar is the default page template in my theme, as it happens.

I have tried editing woocommerce's "archive-product.php" -page. But I just cannot understand, where and how to tell the div's to be situated where I want them to.

My theme's default "page.php"  and "page-left-sidebar.php"-template are identical. Only the template's name (obviously) changes. In my "style.css" I have rules both for default sidebar (sidebar to the right) and page-left-template-sidebar.

What files should I edit and how?

Answer (score 0):

To display sidebar on the left, the style.css file should have property `float:left` for that section

Comment: My style.css does have property "float:left" for sidebar in page-left-template.php. But the question is: how and where to "call" it? Like I wrote, the template shop page is now using, how to say it, wrong lines in my .css file. It is not calling and using the .css for left sidebar, like I want it to, but right, In my style.css I have rules for both left and right sidebars. What is being called in action, is the wrong one.

Comment: For the life of me, I can't figure out where and how this choice of made, why woocommerce overrules my page template settings and places the sidebar to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround... I still don't understand how the default templates work, but I've tried until I give up. I just hard-coded a `div style="right;"` in the archive-product.php, closing the div just before the sidebar commanding lines. It's crude, I know, but it seems to do the trick.